# String Joining from Iterable containing Strings and ( NoneType / Undefined )

Tags: python

I am looking for a clean way to combine variables into a single string with a predefined separator. The problem is that sometimes some of these variables wont always exist or can be set to None. I cant have the separator string duplicate either. Example of problem:

```
# This works because I have all strings
str('-').join(('productX', 'deployment-package', '1.2.3.4'))
# 'productX-deployment-package-1.2.3.4'

# But I have more args that might be None / or not exist like and that breaks
str('-').join(('productX', 'deployment-package', '1.2.3.4', idontexist, alsonotexist))
str('-').join(('productX', 'deployment-package', '1.2.3.4', None, None, None))

# If I set the other missing variables to empty strings, I get duplicated joiners
str('-').join(('productX', 'deployment-package', '1.2.3.4', '', '', ''))
# 'productX-deployment-package-1.2.3.4---'
```

Is there a nice clean way to do this?

Comment: Better to use `'-'.join` instead of `str('-').join`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a comprehension to populate your iterable with a conditional checking that values have a truthy value.

```
your_list = [
  'productX', 
  'deployment-package', 
  '1.2.3.4', 
  None, 
  None, 
  None,
]

'-'.join(item for item in your_list if item)
```

Comment: I prefer this to my own answer, because it also handles empty strings as the OP wants.

Comment: use `if item.strip()` to make it work with empty strings as well.

Comment: You can't use "if item.strip()" as it will fail on None or any other object that doesn't support strip()

Comment: @JonClements what about `if item or item.strip()`

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary: That should be `if item and item.strip()`

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the number of items constant (for instance because you want to output to a spreadsheet where the list is a row and each item represents a column), use:

```
your_list = ['key', 'type', 'frequency', 'context_A', None, 'context_C']
'\t'.join(str(item) for item in your_list)
```

BTW this is also the way to go if any of the items you want to join are integers.

Comment: The way you have this, it puts the value `None` in the string like so `'key,type,frequency,context_A,None,context_C'`. I think most people would want an empty string to be used. For that I use `','.join(item or '' for item in your_list)` to get `'key,type,frequency,context_A,,context_C'`. However, because I had to drop the `str()` wrapper, you can't use it to convert integers.

Comment: this is a great solution if you happen to be validating input where one of the permissible values is None.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `filter(bool, your_list)` or `filter(None, your_list)` to remove anything that evaluates to False when converted to a bool, such as False, None, 0, [], (), {}, '', maybe others.

You can use `locals().get('mightnotexist')` or `globals().get('mightnotexist')`, depending on whether the variable is expected to be local or global, to reference a variable that might not exist. These will return None if the variable doesn't exist.

Your code might become:

```
items = ('productX',
         'deployment-package',
         '1.2.3.4',
         locals().get('idontexist'),
         globals().get('alsonotexist'),
         None,
         None,
         '')
'-'.join(filter(bool, items))
```

Comment: I do prefer this solution because it is in my opinon more readable.